# reading video originBytes and store it in Uint8List cause app crash

Tags: flutter, out-of-memory, photo

I am using Photo Manager package in Flutter app to get photos and videos from the device's gallery and then store them in Uint8List  variable:
Dart package : photo_manager: ^2.6.0

> Uint8List? videoBytes = await selectedFile.originBytes!;

"originBytes: is a future function that returns Future<Uint8List?>

All works fine except for video have size of 95 MB and above, the app crashing and close, Android studio error log is:

> Blockquote
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 100518208 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 60MB until OOM, target footprint 229697624, growth limit 268435456

i have tried get the bytes chunk by chunk but getting same error, i tried to set android:largeHeap="true", also getting the same error

Comment: why would you want to allocate 95M byte array for? cannot you process your file in small chunks?

Comment: Hi pskink, I want to write the whole video in specific file using File.writeAsBytes(videoBytes!).then()

Comment: what i want to do is reading the video from the gallery and write it again in my application directory

Comment: and cannot you use `originFile`? and then call `File.copy()`?

Comment: The copy works only if the target directory is on the same file system as the destination file, which is not in my case

Comment: so use `File.openRead` / `File.openWrite` and call `Stream.pipe` method

Comment: i saw your comment on another question where you mentioned the stream.pipe, i tried to use it but so far i could not make it work, i will read more about pipe, anyway thank you so much for your efforts here and on other questions

Comment: Btw are you sure `copy` will not work? I just took a look into the official `File` docs and they say that `rename` could not work if used on different file systems, they don't say anything when it comes to `copy`

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/rename.html  - "On some platforms, a rename operation cannot move a file between different file systems. If that is the case, instead **copy()** the file to the new location and then remove the original."

Comment: copy might solve changing the path but the android file manager will keep the video's metadata and will keep showing it in the gallery which i dont want, i will try copy and make sure that its removed form the source